# Make first letter of words uppercase in a string

Tags: string, go, title-case

I have a large array of strings such as this one:

```
"INTEGRATED ENGINEERING 5 Year (BSC with a Year in Industry)"
```

I want to capitalise the first letter of the words and make the rest of the words lowercase. So `INTEGRATED` would become `Integrated`.

A second spanner in the works - I want an exception to a few words such as `and`, `in`, `a`, `with`.

So the above example would become:

```
"Integrated Engineering 5 Year (Bsc with a Year in Industry)"
```

How would I do this in Go? I can code the loop/arrays to manage the change but the actual string conversion is what I struggle with.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There is a function in the built-in `strings` package called [`Title`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Title).

```
s := "INTEGRATED ENGINEERING 5 Year (BSC with a Year in Industry)"
fmt.Println(strings.Title(strings.ToLower(s)))
```

https://go.dev/play/p/THsIzD3ZCF9

Comment: How does the answer addresses exceptions mentioned in the question? (and, in a, with)

Comment: Be careful with this function, the strings.Title also make character after `'` upcase.
e.g: `strings.Title("capitlize's me")` => `Capitlize'S Me`

Comment: `strings.Title` is now deprecated: https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Title

Comment: yep, @Micah Parks right. changes: https://pkg.go.dev/strings#ToTitle

Comment: @rtut this is incorrect, `strings.ToTitle()` makes all characters uppercase and doesn't replace `strings.Title()`

Comment: This function is deprecated in new versions of Golang and this package is recommended now ```golang.org/x/text/cases``` for this use case

Answer (score 26):

The below is an [alternate](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/cases#Title) to the accepted answer, which is now [deprecated](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Title):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/cases"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    msg := "INTEGRATED ENGINEERING 5 Year (BSC with a Year in Industry)"
    fmt.Println(cases.Title(language.English, cases.Compact).String(msg))
}
```

Comment: to only make the first letter of the string capital use: `cases.Title(language.English, cases.NoLower).String(msg)`

Answer (score 16):

You can use [regular expressions](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp) for this task. A `\w+` regexp will match all the words, then by using `Regexp.ReplaceAllStringFunc` you can replace the words with intended content, skipping stop words. In your case, `strings.ToLower` and `strings.Title` will be also helpful.

Example:

```
str := "INTEGRATED ENGINEERING 5 Year (BSC with a Year in Industry)"

// Function replacing words (assuming lower case input)
replace := func(word string) string {
    switch word {
    case "with", "in", "a":
        return word
    }
    return strings.Title(word)
}

r := regexp.MustCompile(`\w+`)
str = r.ReplaceAllStringFunc(strings.ToLower(str), replace)

fmt.Println(str)

// Output:
// Integrated Engineering 5 Year (Bsc with a Year in Industry)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/uMag7buHG8

You can easily adapt this to your *array of strings*.

Comment: Use \pL (unicode letter) instead of \w (ascii only) for free text. Your solution gives "Manager Of Two CaféS in QuéBec"). Also, know that title is deprecated (see @TomiEcio's answer).

Answer (score 1):

In Go 1.18 strings.Title() is deprecated.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620717/in-go-1-18-strings-title-is-deprecated-what-to-use-now-and-how) you can read the following to know what to use now

> you should use cases.Title instead.