# How to capitalise first letter of each word in a string in go manually?

Tags: function, go, letter, capitalize

I am trying to write a function manually that capitalises the first letter of each word in a string. For example: "My dog is cute! I+love+my+dog+4ever" to "My Dog Is Cute! I+Love+My+Dog+4ever". I would be glad if you can help me.

```
func Capitalize(s string) string {
L := ToLower(s)
runeL := []rune(L)
len := len(runeL) - 1
Lnew := Concat(ToUpper(string(L[0])), string(runeL[1:len]))
LnewS := []rune(Lnew)
newstrings := []rune{}
for i := range LnewS {
    if IsAlpha(string(LnewS[i])) == true {
        newstrings = append(newstrings, LnewS[i])
    } else {
        newstrings = append(newstrings, LnewS[i])
        if LnewS[i+1] == rune(32) {
            newstrings = append(newstrings)
        }
        if IsLower(string(LnewS[i+1:])) {
            LnewS[i+1] = LnewS[i+1] - rune(32)
        }
    }
}
return string(newstrings)
```

}

Comment: See [Make first letter of words uppercase in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40382340/5728991) , [How to capitalize the first letter of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70259366/5728991).

Comment: I edited now. Thank you for your help. I am not allowed to use functions like title. I started coding one week ago. Sorry in advance if what I wrote is complete nonsense.

Comment: Could you please check my code again? this time it works but it doesn't print the last character of the string.

Answer (score 2):

> How to capitalise first letter of each word in a string in Go
> manually?

---

> In a letter to Robert Hooke in 1675, Isaac Newton made his most famous statement: “If I have seen further it is by standing on the shoulders of Giants”.

Let's follow Newton's advice and read,

The C Programming Language, Second Edition
Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie

In particular, read,

1.5.4 Word Counting

The section introduces a key concept, state variables: "The variable *state* records whether the program is currently in a word or not."

---

If we apply that insight to your problem then we get something like this,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
)

func Capitalize(s string) string {
    rs := []rune(s)
    inWord := false
    for i, r := range rs {
        if unicode.IsLetter(r) || unicode.IsNumber(r) {
            if !inWord {
                rs[i] = unicode.ToTitle(r)
            }
            inWord = true
        } else {
            inWord = false
        }
    }
    return string(rs)
}

func main() {
    s := "My dog is cute! I+love+my+dog+4ever"
    fmt.Println(s)
    t := Capitalize(s)
    fmt.Println(t)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/4QnHIqfGjWy

```
My dog is cute! I+love+my+dog+4ever
My Dog Is Cute! I+Love+My+Dog+4ever
```

---

> [Unicode: Character Properties, Case Mappings & Names FAQ](https://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html)
>
> The titlecase mapping in the Unicode Standard is the mapping applied to the initial character in a word.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the strings package with its title function to capitalize first letter of each word. An example of it can be seen below.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)


func main() {
    var strInput string
    fmt.Println("Enter a string")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    if scanner.Scan() {
        strInput = scanner.Text()
    }

    res := strings.Title(strInput)
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```

If you wanna do it manually, write an algorithm where

- Checks the entire index of the string
- If an index is the first index or it's an alphabet after a space, change that index alphabet into uppercase, and it should work

Comment: Thank you for your answer Amodh! but I am not allowed to use strings package. I need to write a function works as Title function manually. I cannot figure out how I should write.

Comment: FWIW strings.Title() is deprecated in 1.18 https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48367

Comment: It seems `cases.Title(language.AmericanEnglish, cases.NoLower).String(s)` would do similar.

Answer (score 0):

`strings.Title()` has been deprecated. It is recommended that you use `golang.org/x/text/cases` instead. However, the results do not produce the desired output by the OP.

**`cases.Title` Example**

Run the following command in your terminal...

```
go get golang.org/x/text
```

Then you can capitalize each word in a string like this...

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/cases"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    input := "My dog is cute! I+love+my+dog+4ever"
    output := cases.Title(language.English).String(input)
    fmt.Printf(" input=%s\n, output=%s\n", input, output)
}
```

Result

```
 input=My dog is cute! I+love+my+dog+4ever
output=My Dog Is Cute! I+Love+My+Dog+4Ever
                                      ^
OP wants '4ever' not '4Ever'
```

**`cases.Title` Note 1**

This will also turn all uppercase words to only have the first letter uppercase. E.g. `USA` will become `Usa`. You will need to pass `cases.NoLower` to void this behavior.

```golang
func main() {
    input := "the USA"
    output := cases.Title(language.English, cases.NoLower).String(input)
    fmt.Printf(" input=%s\n, output=%s\n", input, output)
}

// Result = "The USA"
```

**`cases.Title` Note 2**

`cases.Title` does not handle abbreviated English ordinal numbers well. For example, `10th` will be transformed to `10Th` and `3rd` will be transformed to `3Rd`.