# In Go 1.18 strings.Title() is deprecated. What to use now? And how?

Tags: go

As suggested [here](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/when-to-capitalize-words/) names of people should be capitalized like `John William Smith`.

I'm writing a small software in Golang which gets last and first name from user's form inputs.

Until Go 1.18 I was using:

```golang
lastname = strings.Title(strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(lastname)))
firstname = strings.Title(strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(firstname)))
```

It works but now Go 1.18 [has deprecated `strings.Title()`](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/48367).

They suggest to use `golang.org/x/text/cases` instead.

So I think I should change my code in something like this:

```golang
caser := cases.Title(language.Und)

lastname = caser.Title(strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(lastname)))
firstname = caser.Title(strings.ToLower(strings.TrimSpace(firstname)))
```

It works the same as before.

The difference is for Dutch word like `ijsland` that should be titled as `IJsland` and not `Ijsland`.

#### The question

In the line `caser := cases.Title(language.Und)` I'm using `Und` because I don't know [what language Tag to use](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text@v0.3.7/language#Tag).

Should I use `language.English` or `language.AmericanEnglish` or other?

So far it was like `strings.Title()` was using `Und` or `English`?

Comment: I was confused by the question - this isn't a difference in behavior between `strings.Title` and `cases.Title`, but a lack of a custom implementation for Dutch. You are correct that there is no such implementation in the standard library; you'll likely need to implement your own if you require that functionality.

Comment: I do not understand the answer. I'm asking about what language I should use.

Comment: And what was/is the "language" of `strings.Title`?

Comment: In theory you can use English as default language and try to infer the language using something from your domain. For instance, if you read from database perhaps you can add a field “language”. Or the language can be a parameter.

Comment: However you should ask yourself if your approach to names is the right one. firstname/lastname are not universal. If you handle asian or middle-east names this will be complex. Perhaps you should use a field “full name” and only Trim(), and add an optio field where people can add a first name to be informally called (or nickname).

Comment: If you are going to take the time to find a replacement for strings.Title, you might also want to examine the assumption that title case is appropriate.

Comment: @Zombo are you talking about my idea to titleize names?

Comment: Consider names like Werner von Braun,  LeVar Burton, Douglas MacArthur, etc..  `strings.Title(strings.ToLower(n))` mangles these names.

Comment: @Zombo. You're right. What to do? Do you have any hint? I don't want to leave to the user this job because people is not good at this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in documentation [strings.Title](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Title) is deprecated and you should use `cases.Title` instead.

> Deprecated: The rule Title uses for word boundaries does not handle
> Unicode punctuation properly. Use golang.org/x/text/cases instead.

Here is an example code of how to use it as from two perspectives:

```
// Straightforward approach
caser := cases.Title(language.BrazilianPortuguese)
titleStr := caser.String(str)

// Transformer interface aware approach
src := []byte(s)
dest := []byte(s) // dest can also be `dest := src`
caser := cases.Title(language.BrazilianPortuguese)
_, _, err := caser.Transform(dest, src, true)
```

Make sure to take a look on the [transform.Transformer.Transform](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/transform#Transformer.Transform) and [cases.Caser](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/text/cases#Caser) in order to understand what each parameter and return values mean, as well as the tool's limitations. For example:

> A Caser may be stateful and should therefore not be shared between
> goroutines.

Regarding what `language` to use, you should be aware of their difference in the results, besides that, you should be fine with any choice. Here is a copy from [煎鱼's summary on the differences](https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041413266/en) that cleared it for me:

Go Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/xp59r1BkC9L

```
func main() {
    src := []string{
        "hello world!",
        "i with dot",
        "'n ijsberg",
        "here comes O'Brian",
    }
    for _, c := range []cases.Caser{
        cases.Lower(language.Und),
        cases.Upper(language.Turkish),
        cases.Title(language.Dutch),
        cases.Title(language.Und, cases.NoLower),
    } {
        fmt.Println()
        for _, s := range src {
            fmt.Println(c.String(s))
        }
    }
}
```

With the following output

```
hello world!
i with dot
'n ijsberg
here comes o'brian

HELLO WORLD!
İ WİTH DOT
'N İJSBERG
HERE COMES O'BRİAN

Hello World!
I With Dot
'n IJsberg
Here Comes O'brian

Hello World!
I With Dot
'N Ijsberg
Here Comes O'Brian
```

Answer (score 6):

> So far it was like `strings.Title()` was using `Und` or `English`?

`strings.Title()` works [based on ASCII](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18:src/strings/strings.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.18;l=687), where `cases.Title()` works based on Unicode, there is no way to get the exact same behavior.

> Should I use language.English or language.AmericanEnglish or other?

`language.English`, `language.AmericanEnglish` and `language.Und` all seem to have the [same Title rules](https://cs.opensource.google/go/x/text/+/refs/tags/v0.3.7:cases/map.go;l=92). Using any of them should get you the closest to the original `strings.Title()` behavior as you are going to get.

The whole point of using this package with Unicode support is that it is objectively more correct. So pick a tag appropriate for your users.

Answer (score 5):

`strings.Title(str)` was deprecated, should change to `cases.Title(language.Und, cases.NoLower).String(str)`

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "golang.org/x/text/cases"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)
func main() {
    fmt.Println(strings.Title("abcABC"))                                   // AbcABC
    fmt.Println(cases.Title(language.Und, cases.NoLower).String("abcABC")) // AbcABC
}
```

Playground : https://go.dev/play/p/i0Eqh3QfxTx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a straightforward example of how to capitalize the initial letter of each string value in the variable using the golang.org/x/text package.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/text/cases"
    "golang.org/x/text/language"
)

func main() {
    sampleStr := "with value lower,  all the letters are lowercase. this is good for poetry perhaps"
    caser := cases.Title(language.English)
    fmt.Println(caser.String(sampleStr))
}
```

Output : With Value Lower,  All The Letters Are Lowercase. This Is Good For Poetry Perhaps

Playground Example: https://go.dev/play/p/_J8nGVuhYC9

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but it seems to just duplicate existing answers.